# How to run python script inside django project?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-1.11

I am unable to run python script inside my django project.

1. I have create a directory with `mkdir scripts`
2. Then I use `touch scripts/__init__.py`
3. Then I create my python script using `touch scripts/update_keyword.py`
4. here is the code of my script

```
def run():
    # Fetch all questions
    print("run script")
```

Then I run my script with the help of the following command:

```
python manage.py runscript update_keyword.py
```

Now I am getting following error:

```
Unknown command: 'runscript'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
```

I have follow this blog https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/runscript.html . Kindly Help.

Comment: have you added `django_extensions` in installed apps ??

Comment: write a bash script which will call your python script. Please check your export path. @saiful

Comment: You're using `django-extensions` so you should make sure you follow the [installation instructions](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation_instructions.html)

Comment: please don't change your question to a follow-up question once it was answered. Create a new question.

Comment: Thanks all . I have added django_extensions but getting database issue. I have update the answer. Please have a look.

Comment: OK I will comply in future @dirkgroten . Thanks and I have roll back.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Django does not know this command since it is not listed anywhere. When you want to run a command with `manage.py`, use [Django's Admin Command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-management-commands/).

**EDIT** Or if you really want to use `django_extensions` for some reason, use their [GitHub docs](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions) as reference. There it states you need to add this app to `INSTALLED_APPS`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'django_extensions',
    ...
)
```

Comment: Use `pip install django-extensions` to install django-extention.

Answer (score 3):

Check the installation:

https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation_instructions.html

I guess you have missed this:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'django_extensions',
)
```